# I'm trying to run an AppImage on multipass, but it won't open a window

Tags: 20.04, appimage, multipass

I recently downloaded an App Image onto multipass and was hoping to run it, but when I did the terminal did this:

```
ubuntu@multipass1~$./appimage.appimage
ubuntu@multipass1~$
```

Nothing happened, no window opened. I know I probably have to install something, but what?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multipass is just for shell, but you can install the ubuntu desktop and install an rdp tool.

Based on [this ubuntu tutorial](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/graphical-desktop-in-multipass/16229) here is how you can do that:

First go into the shell of your multipass instance, `multipass shell my-multipass-name`. Replace 'my-multipass-name' with your multipass instance name. If you don't know the name, use `multipass list` to find all instances.

Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` to update your multipass system.

After that's done, you need to install the ubuntu desktop and an rdp tool, `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop xrdp`. APT should get you all the packages necessary.

Once you get the neccesary packages, you need to set a passwd for remoting into the system. `sudo passwd [username]`. Replace [username] with the username of your machine. If you didn't create a new user, the default is ubuntu.

Your guest ubuntu is now ready! Now we have to use your host system.

Install a program that uses xrdp:

Windows: You have the 'Remote Desktop Application'. Enter the IP (can be found in `multipass list`.

macOS/iOS: Install the 'Microsoft Remote Desktop' in the app store.

Linux: Remmina, you have to also have `remmina-plugin-rdp` along with the default `remmina` package on your host, otherwise it won't work.